# How to make my servo slow down in it´s movement

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, servo

I want to make my servo react on the data that my light sensor tells him by the amount of light that it is catching. I want the servo to go fast to the left when there is shadow/darkness and then I want it to go slowly back to the right when the light is back.

This is the code I´m now using for my 180 degrees servo.
I also want this to work on my 360 degrees servo but because I am a beginner, I can´t figure it out...

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo s;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  s.attach(9);
}

void loop() {
   float l = analogRead(A0);
   Serial.print(l);
   Serial.print(" ");
   int v = map(l,0,1024,0,179);
   s.write(v);
   Serial.println(v);

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. Don't post code as a picture. Copy and paste it into your question and use correct formatting there (mark the code and press Control + K to format it as block code). 2. Don't post just images of your circuit. We are not really able to see much on these. Instead draw a schematic. You can use the internal schematics editor of this site, when you edit your question. Or, if you don't understand schematics at this point in your learning, use something easier like Fritzing. 3. Describe better, why you are not able to use a 360° servo with your code. What is happening, if you try it?

Comment: I don't really understand, what your exact target is, but you have to watch out when using a 360° servo. Some of them are actually continuous rotation servos, where you don't set the angle with the `Servo.write()` function, but the rotation speed (so a value of 90 would mean no movement)

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with the light sensor .... you can remove all the code that has anything to do with the sensor ...... develop the code to control the motor first ..... if you cannot get the motor to run slowly, then it is pointless to go on without changing your goal

Comment: I added the code, pictures from my circuit in the right way now.
Hope that it's better to understand and help from now.

Answer (score 2):

The servo's rotation speed is controlled by its internal circuitry. Once you send it a new target position, it drives at it's maximum speed toward that position and decelerates as it approaches.

The best you can do to slow it down is to change its target stepwise, until you reach the target position, instead of setting the final target all at once. If you move it in several large steps, the motion will be jerky; if you send smaller steps at shorter intervals (so the total travel time will be same), the motion will get smoother.

If your application needs the smoothest motion possible, send it many tiny steps rapidly, again, observing your required total travel time. You should be able keep the servo constantly at (or closer to) it's approach speed.